# Kafka Java Producer not creating message when used inside docker container.

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am sure I am missing some setting but not sure which one. Using kafka 0.9.0 and kafka is deployed on host machine. I am running Docker containers containing my Java App which produces message.

When I deployed java app on host machine it works fine and all messages get queued but not from inside container. No errors found in logs.

Here is my Producer settings

```
public void configureProducer() {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", env.getProperty("kafka.bootstrap.servers"));
        props.put("acks", env.getProperty("kafka.ack"));
        props.put("retries", env.getProperty("kafka.retries"));
        props.put("batch.size", env.getProperty("kafka.batch.size"));
        props.put("linger.ms", env.getProperty("kafka.linger.ms"));
        props.put("buffer.memory", env.getProperty("kafka.buffer.memory"));
        props.put("key.serializer", env.getProperty("kafka.key.serializer"));
        props.put("value.serializer", env.getProperty("kafka.value.serializer"));

        producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
    }
```

And values

```
kafka.bootstrap.servers=myhost.dev:9092
kafka.ack=0
kafka.retries=0
kafka.batch.size=16384
kafka.linger.ms=1
kafka.buffer.memory=33554432
kafka.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
kafka.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Comment: See whether you can ping the host machine IP from the docker container

Comment: Yes I can. I have database server and consul also on host machine and everything is accessible from docker. I have added the host entry.